# My notification only works when App is open, why?

Tags: java, android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, push

I have an App here that receives pushes from GCM, I configured It to show an specific icon and action, but it only happens when the App is open; when I kill it or close the app, the notification shows another message and another icon (which one is set on server side, in Java), and I want to use **only** the app`s code version notification.

This is the onReceive code:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                intent, 0);
        Notification.Builder nb = new Notification.Builder(context);
        nb.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        nb.setContentTitle("Nova aprovacao cadastrada!");
        nb.setContentText(message.getAlert());
        nb.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        Notification notification = nb.build();     
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;        
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        notificationManager.notify(R.drawable.ic_launcher, notification);
```

The ic_launcher is the icon that i want to show, but as i said, only works with the app opened.

In the manifest, I put:

```
  <receiver
            android:name="..."
            android:permission="..." 
            android:exported="true" >
```

Please, ignore the '...'.

**Update note**

*I read a post here that when you close your app, the BroadcastReceiver keep running. But in my case, I do not have this class and I do not use It. There is some how to keep my onReceive running while it is closed?*

- **Problem:** Notification does not work as I expected when app is closed.
- **Question:** How fix this using only the Android code?

Thanks!

Comment: try changing your last line in the sendNotification method to `notificationManager.notify(0 /*ID of notification*/, notification);`

Comment: @mikebertian It did not work, thx anyway ;)

Comment: Are you using any push notification service providers like Urban Airship?

Comment: @prasad rao No, but yes, i'm using a service, unfortunately I can not tell you which, but I`m starting to think that is a life cycle problem. I'll update my post to you see, it is related to the BroadcastReceiver, I guess.

Comment: Where does this onReceive code exist? In an activity?

Comment: i don't understand how you have an onReceive if you don't have a BroadcastReceiver

Comment: @steve It is inside the onCreate() in a acitivty, is it wrong?

Comment: @njzk2 I use a custom NotificationListener, that call the onReceive but this works fine

Comment: Yes. Like you said you need to use a BroadcastReceiver. The activity life cycle is going to cause all sorts of problems for you.

Comment: In custom push service providers you will have an option to modify the default push notification at the time of registering your app to the service provider, probably in Application controller. So that when your app is not in running state, you will get the notification by the way you want.